# Optimal low-rank approximation of a matrix for given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

Given a target matrix $\mathbf{T}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ and a basis (not necessarily orthonormal) $\mathbf{V}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times K}$, how would I find the optimal reconstruction of $\mathbf{T}$

$$\min_{\mathbf{D}} \left\| \mathbf{T-VDV}^{H} \right\|_F \quad s.t. \mathbf{D}\: \mathrm{diagonal}$$

So far I recognize this is equivalent to finding the optimal $\sigma$ to minimize:

$$\min_{\mathbf{\sigma}} \left\| \mathbf{T}-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^K \sigma_i \mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{v}_i^H\Big) \right\|_F$$

where $\mathbf{v}_i$ is column $i$ of $\mathbf{V}$. I suspect the optimal $\sigma$ values are related to the magnitude of $\mathbf{T}$'s projection onto each $\mathbf{v}_i$, but have not managed to make anything work so far.

Comment: Is there a connection with Singular Value Decomposition ?

Comment: I think this is a more difficult problem than the typical SVD low rank approximation problem because the the basis V is not composed of eigenvectors of T

Comment: Isn't this just a linear least squares problem?

Comment: You should square the Frobenius norms.

Comment: If $M\ne K$, then you do not have a basis. You simply have a set of $K$ vectors in $\mathbb C^M$.

Comment: Anyway, this is a linear least-squares problem in $\boldsymbol\sigma=[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_K]^T$, namely $$\min_{\boldsymbol\sigma}\,\lVert\operatorname{vec}\mathbf T-\mathbf W\sigma\rVert_2^2$$ where $\mathbf W$ is the matrix whose columns are $\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf v_i\mathbf v_i^H)$.